# plone.scale annotation bloated with (usesless?) scales

Tags: performance, plone, zodb

While investigating a `ConflictError` ([see this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19449479)) I saw a lot of `persistent.mapping.PersistentMapping` conflicts.

Looking at a specific one it turned out to be a PersistentMapping for `plone.scale`.

Turns out that a random object with just one image has **562** keys on it, no wonder *why* it gets a conflict error...

Some context on the object that holds this `plone.scale` annotation:
- dexterity content type
- one of its behaviors has an image field (`plone.namedfile.field.NamedBlobImage`)

The code to see it is as following:

Start a debugging instance: `./bin/instance debug`

```
from ZODB.utils import p64
OID = 0x568428  # got from zeo client logs
mapping = app._p_jar[p64(OID)]
len(mapping)  # that returns 562
```

The mysterious part is that only 4 keys on that persistent mapping are tuples, while the other 558 are just hashes.

A brief look at [plone.scale.storage.AnnotationStorage.scale](https://github.com/plone/plone.scale/blob/master/plone/scale/storage.py#L59) method seems to imply that there should be only one to one relation from tuples and hashes keys on the persistent mapping.

Further investigating the elements reveals that, indeed, if you look at the `width` and `height` properties from all elements there are only 4 different combinations (the ones from the tuples itself).

As a new scale is generated whenever the modified time is bigger (see the scale method pointed above) and [plone.namedfield.scaling.ImageScaling.modified](https://github.com/plone/plone.namedfile/blob/master/plone/namedfile/scaling.py#L254) uses context as the source for modified, that means that at every single update of the object a new scale will be generated?

So two questions arise from the previous:

- my assumption of only 4 scales are really used and the other 558 are old and useless is true?
- provided a yes on the previous, shouldn't they be cleaned up then?

Answer (score 3):

You may be right, but surely the correct place to report this is https://dev.plone.org/newticket

Comment: Yeah, but asking here first to see if you have missed something obvious is a good idea.

Comment: I had the time to prepare a tests and a patch (one liner actually): https://github.com/plone/plone.scale/pull/3